# How to create an external databate to test rest API classes

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, httpcalloutmock, heroku

I have been doing some trailheads for REST api's I managed to create a callout class with a mock response based on a static resource, whitch gives me 100% coverage.

I would like to see my Callout in action without connecting it to the real endpoint. What is the fastes / easy way to create an external database to simulate my Get and Post calls as if it were the real endpoint.

I tried another trailhead with heroku connect which connects to salesforce and gets my object and fields. Can I use this to test my Rest API calls or should I go another route. I googled for some answers but could not find some clear explanation for this. Please some direction or articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce also has its own inbuilt library of REST API which you can make request to get response and parse them.

For example get organization limit.

```
curl https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/limits/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

In token, you can use session Id.

Here is a [complete list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_user_tasks.htm) for your reference.